# how to make fishbowl(WPF Client for Facebook) multi-user compatible

Tags: wpf

I need to make the fishbowl application (which is a WPF application for Facebook) multi-user compatible. It seems, it's only supporting single user login via facebook. Any ideas how to make it multi-user compatible.

applicate you help.

-Aruna

Answer (score 0):

i found the solution to do this, it's easy

have to comment the _TryGetCachedSession() function and have to stop  calling InitializeAsFirstInstance() function in the start-up